# Custom Role in VSTS to allow Add Users

Tags: permissions, azure-devops

I’m trying to create a custom role to assign to users to allow them to add users to a project.

[MS’ documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/add-users-team-project#prerequisites) on this claims the custom role just needs to be “edit project-level information” and "edit instance-level information" but that doesn’t work. In fact if I set Allow to all the possible permissions, my test user still can’t add others to the project.

My test user can **only** add other users to the project if they are made a Project Team Administrator or added to the built-in Project Administrators group.

But I've been asked: is it possible to have a reduced set of permissions to allow users to be added to a project without being a full blown administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

1. You could first create a group as a container to put the user who
   just need the permission to add users.
2. Then add the group member of **Project Administrators** as below
   screeshot:

   [image]
3. Deny other not related or you don't want to give project-level
   permissions (expect **edit project-level information** ) for that
   group, since in TFS **Deny trumps Allow**.

   [image]
4. Finally add the user to that specific group.

The user could be able to add others in the team project. However, for other areas with deny setting. He will get `You don't have permissions to perform the action.`

Detail description for each project-level permission, please refer this [**link**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#nbspnbspnbspproject-level).

Comment: That works. One further question: Do you know why it is this way around? Why (essentially) give the user admin rights, then pare those rights back; rather than simply giving the user the rights he needs?

Comment: @Rincey_nz Due to there are not  rights which explicitly stands for adding user in team project , only give the user "edit project-level information" permission will not  work, however without "edit project-level information" in admin group will also not able to add user. So you have to use this workaround. Besides use group to manage permission is more convenient, you could simply add/remove users, not need to change each permission for the users if you want to change the permission again.